# How can I print four copies of single image on a sheet of paper, one in each corner?

Tags: printing, image-processing

I have an image in tif format and I want to print 4 copies of the image on the same piece of paper. Is there a way to do this in Ubuntu 12?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example for making a comp with ImageMagick.

```
convert xc:white -page A4 \
    -page +0+0 image.tiff \
    -page +250+0 image.tiff \
    -page +0+250 image.tiff \
    -page +250+250 image.tiff \
    -flatten output.pdf
```

I don't know what the exact coordinates will be, but try this and play around with it.

The quick alternative would just be using something like Inkscape or GIMP to create a composition manually.

Comment: thanks a lot. worked well, since the image was small great idea